# How to prove unique adherent value

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $s_n$ be a real sequence and $m_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n s_n$. We denote $t_n=\alpha s_n+(1-\alpha)m_n$ where $\alpha>0$.

Assume that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n=l$$

Prove that

- $\{m_n\}$ is bounded.
- $\{m_n\}$ has only one value of adherence.

The first part I solve by considering $m_n=\frac{n\alpha}{n\alpha+1}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n\alpha+1}t_n$ and $t_n$ is bounded.

I have tried to prove the second by contradiction but it's getting nowhere. By the geometrical intuition I believe that the value of $m_n$ must lie between $l+\varepsilon$ and $m_{n-1}$ and there fore it cannot jump out to another adherent value, but I don't know how to make it rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for the case $0<\alpha<1$. Put $S_n=s_0+\cdots+s_n$. We have $S_n-S_{n-1}=s_n$ for $n\geq 1$. We get
$$t_n=(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha}{n+1})S_n-\alpha S_{n-1}$$
or
$$(1+\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha(n+1)})S_n=S_{n-1}+\frac{t_n}{\alpha}$$

Now put $\displaystyle a_n=\prod_{k=0}^n (1+\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha(k+1)})$. Multiplying by $a_{n-1}$, we get
$$a_nS_n=a_{n-1}S_{n-1}+\frac{a_{n-1}t_n}{\alpha}=a_{n-1}S_{n-1}+\frac{n+1}{\alpha n+1}a_n t_n$$

Hence
$$a_nS_n=a_0S_0+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{\alpha k+1}t_k a_k$$

Now 
$$\log a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \log (1+\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha(k+1)})=\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}+b_n$$ with $b_n$ convergent sequence, and hence

$$\log a_n=\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}\log n+c_n$$
with $c_n$ another convergent sequence.

We get $\displaystyle a_n\sim Ln^{(1-\alpha)/\alpha}$ with $L>0$. Now it is easy to see that $\displaystyle a_0+\cdots+a_n\sim \alpha L n^{1/\alpha}\sim \alpha (n+1)a_n$.

We have $$m_n=\frac{S_n}{n+1}=\frac{a_0S_0}{(n+1)a_n}+\frac{1}{(n+1)a_n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{\alpha k+1}t_k a_k=A+B$$

By the above, we have $A\to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$. Put $\displaystyle r_k=\frac{k+1}{\alpha k+1}t_k$, we have that $\displaystyle r_k\to \frac{l}{\alpha}$.  As $a_k>0$ for all $k$, and $\displaystyle a_1+\cdots a_n\to +\infty$ we get by a generalised Cesaro theorem that

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n r_ka_k}{\sum_{k=1}^na_k}\to \frac{l}{\alpha}$$
Hence $B\to l$, and $m_n\to l$.

The case $\alpha=1$ is trivial, and perhaps the case $\alpha>1$ can be studied as above.

Comment: Actually the point is to prove the two conditions to deduce that $m_n\rightarrow l$, which may be easier than your way. However +1 for such a great effort.